# Коэффициенты регрессии в R

Tags: r

Я хочу сделать логистическую регрессию в R чтобы считать вероятность какого то события. У меня есть база, на ее основе я сделал регрессию и получил вот это:

```
    Call:
glm(formula = hd ~ ., family = "binomial", data = data)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-3.0490  -0.4847  -0.1213   0.3039   2.9086  

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept) -6.253978   2.960399  -2.113 0.034640 *  
age         -0.023508   0.025122  -0.936 0.349402    
sexM         1.670152   0.552486   3.023 0.002503 ** 
cp2          1.448396   0.809136   1.790 0.073446 .  
cp3          0.393353   0.700338   0.562 0.574347    
cp4          2.373287   0.709094   3.347 0.000817 ***
trestbps     0.027720   0.011748   2.359 0.018300 *  
chol         0.004445   0.004091   1.087 0.277253    
fbs1        -0.574079   0.592539  -0.969 0.332622    
restecg1     1.000887   2.638393   0.379 0.704424    
restecg2     0.486408   0.396327   1.227 0.219713    
thalach     -0.019695   0.011717  -1.681 0.092781 .  
exang1       0.653306   0.447445   1.460 0.144267    
oldpeak      0.390679   0.239173   1.633 0.102373    
slope2       1.302289   0.486197   2.679 0.007395 ** 
slope3       0.606760   0.939324   0.646 0.518309    
ca3          2.237444   0.514770   4.346 1.38e-05 ***
ca4          3.271852   0.785123   4.167 3.08e-05 ***
ca5          2.188715   0.928644   2.357 0.018428 *  
thal3       -0.168439   0.810310  -0.208 0.835331    
thal4        1.433319   0.440567   3.253 0.001141 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  
0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 409.95  on 296  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 183.10  on 276  degrees of freedom
AIC: 225.1

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 6
```

В моей базе были графы `cp,fbs,restecg` и тд, И я не понимаю почему в таблице коэффициентов они стали чем то вроде `cp2,cp3,cp4`
В столбце `cp` у меня значения 1,2,3,4. И я догадываюсь что это как то связано но не понимаю как.
Как мне подставлять веса регрессии в формулу чтобы посчитать вероятность, если у меня один параметр разбился на 4?

Comment: Сделайте one-hot encoding факторов и всё встанет на свои места.

Comment: Посмотрите в интернете про dummy-переменные в регрессии.